# find all HealthcareService resources for a given Practitioner - fhir search

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

I'm struggling a bit with reverse chaining in fhir search.

I can find all PractitionerRole resources for a given Practitioner with:

`[base]/PractitionerRole?practitioner:Practitioner:id=100`

How do I combine chaning and reverse chaining to find all HealthcareService resources for a given Practitioner? I tried the below and some variations of it.

`[base]/HealthcareService?_has:PractitionerRole:practitioner:Practitioner:id=100`

Answer (score 0):

I would use:
`[base]/PractitionerRole?practitioner=100&_include=PractitionerRole.service`

It's more likely to be supported, and would also give you the roles in which the Practitioner is associated with the service.

Comment: With and without the _include param, results are same. I guess it's not supported, may be, in hapi-fhir. Thanks for your response.